# What is the linux command to find out the number of socket currently open?

Tags: linux, socket

I use that :

```
sudo watch lsof -i -4 -a -P
```

and it returns a list.

how to get the count?

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
sudo watch lsof -i -4 -a -P | wc -l
```

Comment: This is more of a sys admin question. Voting to close. Expecting it will be migrated to ServerFault

Answer (score 3):

I agree, this should probably be on ServerFault.

But, until then:

The issue with what you are doing is the watch command.  Watch repeats a command so that you can see the output again and again over time.

My lsof doesn't accept a -4 argument, but if yours does, then

```
sudo lsof -i -4 -a -P | wc -l
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

To get the count, you need escape quotes to contain the entire command for the shells spawned by watch:

(Also, -4 didn't work here)

```
sudo watch "lsof -i -a -P | wc -l "
```

Answer (score 1):

try `netstat -a | wc -l f`or all type of open sockets and `netstat -l | wc -l` for displaying server sockets.